# Reset counter in node-red

Tags: javascript, node-red

I'm sending an automated email every time the system receives a certain number of messages from an IoT Hub, but I'm struggling in the part of resetting the counter of these messages. The system so far is the following:

[image: Node-red]

I'm getting the Json messages from the Azure receiver, checking if one of the parametres is avobe a certain threshold, if so increasing the counter and if the counter is above another threshold I'm sending an email with a warning.

What I'd like is that counter to be reseted once the email is send so start over again and in the "Write email" box it does reset, but I'm seeing the msg variables are not global and cannot connect both function boxes to communicate between them and make the "count" one reset the variable.

Any hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node-red handles state through shared memory space named **contexts**. The context  is either scoped by node, flow or globally accessible.

In your particular case, you should use the flow context, so your counter will be available to you other nodes for processing.

You can find more details about contexts page on the [official documentation](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/context) as pointed out by @hardillb in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684798/reset-counter-in-node-red#comment94230206_53685795).

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer for whomever going through the same:

https://tech.scargill.net/node-red-global-flow-and-context/

Using global or flow variables will solve the issue.

Comment: This is a link only answer and will likely be deleted if you don't add the actual details here

Comment: The documentation for the context of on the node-red site here https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/context